# Lucky Strike cigarettes—it's toasted (meaning?)

Tags: meaning

Right under the brand name *Lucky Strike*, it says **"it's toasted."** Any idea what that means?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Lucky Strike - It's toasted!]

As this excellent advertising poster from 1917 explains, Lucky Strike tobacco is toasted to hold its flavour - as opposed to the sun-drying method, which supposedly doesn't allow the tobacco to retain its flavour so well. As to exactly what the toasting process consists of, I have no idea, and as far as I can tell it's a closely-guarded secret!

A little more information about the slogan "It's toasted" as an advertising campaign can be [found here](https://www.quora.com/Who-actually-came-up-with-the-Its-toasted-tagline-for-Lucky-Strike-in-real-life).

Comment: The little note in the lower right corner says "Our men will demonstrate to you how the tobacco is toasted - at many stores", so we just have to find out which ones (;